# Check if IP address is in private network space

Tags: go, network-programming, ip

I have a program in go which accepts URLs from clients and gets them using the net/http package. Before doing further processing, I would like to check if the URL maps to private (non-routable / RFC1918 networks) address space.

The straight-forward way would be to perform an explicit DNS request and check the address for the known private ranges. After that, perform the HTTP GET request for the URL.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Preferably integrating with http.Client so it can be performed as a part of the GET request.

Comment: What is "private network space"? The RFC1918 networks?

Comment: I ran into exactly this and found: no there is no better alternative. See https://github.com/mhausenblas/clump/blob/master/main.go#L83

Comment: Sorry, yes, the RFC1918 networks. I updated the question to state this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you just want to log if the host is in a private network, or is there something else you need to do before making the request? @MichaelHausenblas: FYI a `net.IPNet` has a [`Contains` method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPNet.Contains)

Comment: For one use case I want to abort the GET request for RFC1918 networks. For another case I would just log the IP address and whether it's private or public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be easier to do with Go 1.17 (Q4 2021, 5 years later), as [reported by Go 101](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1392852567281963008):

See [commit c73fccc](https://github.com/6543-forks/go/commit/c73fccc384c699f857abd0a566bbbc1529969fd9) and [CL 272668](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/272668/7..11):

> ### `net`: add `IP.IsPrivate()`
>
> Add `IsPrivate()` helper to check if an IP is private according to RFC 1918 & RFC 4193

That fixes [golang issue 29146](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29146) raised by [Aaran McGuire](https://github.com/aaranmcguire):

> The net package seems to have many helpers to report what an IP is. e.g:
>
> - `IsLoopback()`
> - `IsMulticast()`
> - `IsInterfaceLocalMulticast()`
>
> However there are no helpers to report if a IP address is in the private ranges ([RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) & [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193)).

Comment: @StefanOS Thank you for the edit. Much appreciated.

Comment: Btw I expect to change the accepted answer to this one once Go 1.17 is released.

Answer (score 31):

You might also want to include checks for loopback (IPv4 or IPv6) and/or IPv6 link-local or unique-local addresses.  Here is an example with a list of RFC1918 address plus these others and a simple check against them as `isPrivateIP(ip net.IP)`:

```
var privateIPBlocks []*net.IPNet

func init() {
    for _, cidr := range []string{
        "127.0.0.0/8",    // IPv4 loopback
        "10.0.0.0/8",     // RFC1918
        "172.16.0.0/12",  // RFC1918
        "192.168.0.0/16", // RFC1918
        "169.254.0.0/16", // RFC3927 link-local
        "::1/128",        // IPv6 loopback
        "fe80::/10",      // IPv6 link-local
        "fc00::/7",       // IPv6 unique local addr
    } {
        _, block, err := net.ParseCIDR(cidr)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("parse error on %q: %v", cidr, err))
        }
        privateIPBlocks = append(privateIPBlocks, block)
    }
}

func isPrivateIP(ip net.IP) bool {
    if ip.IsLoopback() || ip.IsLinkLocalUnicast() || ip.IsLinkLocalMulticast() {
        return true
    }

    for _, block := range privateIPBlocks {
        if block.Contains(ip) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
  }
```

Comment: Also `fc00::/7`

Comment: missing IPv4  linkLocal:
`"169.254.0.0/16" // RFC3927 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address`


Or in addition:

`ip.IsLoopback() || ip.IsLinkLocalUnicast() || ip.IsLinkLocalMulticast()`

Comment: more complete lists: https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/blob/master/bdns/dns.go and adapted in different way: https://github.com/wader/filtertransport/blob/master/filter.go

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(privateIPCheck("1.1.1.1"))  // False since this is not a private IP
    fmt.Println(privateIPCheck("10.8.0.1")) // True: Since this is a private ip.
}

// Check if a ip is private.
func privateIPCheck(ip string) bool {
    ipAddress := net.ParseIP(ip)
    return ipAddress.IsPrivate()
}
```

This requires Go 1.17.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's no better way to accomplish than the one I described. Combining code from @MichaelHausenblas with the suggestion from @JimB, my code ended up kind of like this.

```
func privateIP(ip string) (bool, error) {
    var err error
    private := false
    IP := net.ParseIP(ip)
    if IP == nil {
        err = errors.New("Invalid IP")
    } else {
        _, private24BitBlock, _ := net.ParseCIDR("10.0.0.0/8")
        _, private20BitBlock, _ := net.ParseCIDR("172.16.0.0/12")
        _, private16BitBlock, _ := net.ParseCIDR("192.168.0.0/16")
        private = private24BitBlock.Contains(IP) || private20BitBlock.Contains(IP) || private16BitBlock.Contains(IP)
    }
    return private, err
}
```

Comment: Something is missing here. You check for the IP, but I can create a DNS that will answer a public IP on the first call, then 127.0.0.1 on the second call. This is called DNS rebind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding

How did you protect for this?

Comment: I agree that could be an issue depending on what your use case, and as far as I know there's no possibility to guard against this using http.Client.

Comment: I found a way :) This article explain it very well: https://linkai.io/blog/securely-issuing-http-requests-from-the-cloud/ I tried (and applied) it and I have no issue :+1:

Comment: @StefanOS To summarize from the linkai.io article lyrixx mentioned: You restrict the http.Clients underlying TCP and TLS mechanisms itself to not issue requests to some IPs when constructing it. This way, the actual request or even redirect is checked the moment it is done and there are no timing issues.
At least when disallowing requests, I guess you could also change the domain for the resolved IP address (that is checked) and make a request to that checked IP, but I'm not sure this is enough. The other method with the http.Client seems way cleaner and easier to reason about for me.