# API to check whether an IP/hostname is local

Tags: go

Is there an easy API in Go to figure out whether a given IP address / hostname belongs to the local machine?

Comment: You will have to [enumerate all network interfaces](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces) and their addresses and compare them to the address in question. [os.Hostname](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Hostname) returns the hostname.

Comment: maybe this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825191/2126159